# EOF via scanf, returned value -65

Tags: c, ubuntu, macros, eof

I need to write my implementation of 'strcmp' as an assignment in my "System Programming Laboratory", just a fancy name for C course.
When I tested the code vs the standard version, it worked in any case except at EOF, in which it automatically returned -1 in the standard version, and in mine, it will start to compare and return 0,1,-1 accordingly.
I want to write a macro to handle this case.

I am using:
*VMware Workstation 17 Player to run
Ubuntu 16.04 (these are the uni's requirements).*

I've tried:

```
#define EOF_CHECK(s1, s2) if ((s1)[0] == EOF || (s2)[0] == EOF ) return -1;
```

and,

```
#define EOF_CHECK(s1, s2) if ((s1)[0] == '\0' || (s2)[0] == '\0' ) return -1;
```

and,

```
#define EOF_CHECK(s1, s2) if ((s1) == NULL || (s2) == NULL ) return -1;
```

None of them worked.
I printed the value after scanf received EOF, and the result is (-65) decimal.
This macro does work:

```
#define EOF_CHECK(s1, s2) if ((s1)[0] == -65  || (s2)[0] == -65  ) return -1;
```

but **I want to avoid magic numbers.**

Comment: You need to check what `scanf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value) to detect errors or end-of-file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I did, it returned (-65) for some weird reason.

Comment: Are you really checking the actual return value of the `scanf` function call? Not the contents or values of variables used in the call? The macros you show seems to check the contents of strings, and if `scanf` fails then those strings will not be updated. Please try to create a proper [mre] and [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: You do not show how you would use those macros. We cannot tell what exactly is wrong. We can only guess from the way you use `s1` and `s2` you are probably not using the correct values. But that is just a blank guess. You should show us a complete minimum example of what you are donig.

Comment: show full code as your description of the problem makes is far from being clear

Comment: So you claim `scanf` returns -65? That doesn't make any sens, `scanf` cannot possibly return -65. Or did something else return -65? Please [edit] and make that clear. Your question is totally unclear. You need to show your actual code along with input and expected vs actual output. Read this: [ask]. And this: [mcve].

Comment: bar toplian, post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

> I need to write my implementation of `strcmp` as an assignment

There is no connection between `strcmp` and `EOF`.  `EOF` is not a character value, it should not be stored into a string.  If `scanf` returned `EOF` when reading the string from `stdin`, nothing was stored into the destination array, which potentially remains uninitialized.  This condition must be tested prior to using the string.  Thus no specific test is needed for `EOF` when handling string contents.

`strcmp` compares the characters in the strings as `unsigned char` values up to and including the null terminator.  It returns `0` if both strings compare equal for all characters and have the same length, otherwise it return a negative value (`-1` or any other negative value) if the first character that does not compare equal in both strings has a value less than that of the second string (the comparison is performed on the `unsigned char` values).  Otherwise, it returns a positive value (`1` or some other value).  A classic implementation returns the difference of the character values, which may be `-65` if you compare for example `""` and `"A"`.

`scanf` is a totally separate function, that is **much** more difficult to reimplement.

I recommend you don't use macros in your assignments, especially macros that expand to statements, which are very error prone as they hide flow control constructions.

Here is a typical implementation of `strcmp`:

```
// Assuming UCHAR_MAX <= INT_MAX
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    /* use unsigned char for comparisons */
    const unsigned char *p1 = (const unsigned char *)s1;
    const unsigned char *p2 = (const unsigned char *)s2;
    for (; *p1 == *p2; p1++, p2++) {
        if (*p1 == '\0')
            return 0;
    }
    return *p1 - *p2;
}
```

Comment: Detail: "EOF is not a character value, it cannot be stored into a string." --> hmmm, when `char` is _signed_, easy to store -1 in a `char` as part of a _string_.

Comment: Pedantic: "strcmp compares the characters in the strings as unsigned char values up to and including the null terminator." is true, yet posted code does not certainly _compare_ using `unsigned char` access.  Likely only makes a difference in the soon to be non-supported non-2's complement encoding.

Comment: Also note that on Windows the character value `26` can actually be interpreted as end-of-file. For example if reading it from a text-file or console. It corresponds to the `Ctrl-Z` used as end-of-file in Windows consoles.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: yes you are correct, yet the letter of the Standard is somewhat ambiguous, **7.25.4 Comparison functions** *The sign of a nonzero value returned by the comparison functions `memcmp`, `strcmp`, and `strncmp` is determined by the sign of the difference between the values of the first pair of characters (both interpreted as `unsigned char`) that differ in the objects being compared.* can be interpreted as comparing with `(unsigned char)*s1 == (unsigned char)*s2` which make no difference with `*s1 == *s2` as negative zeroes convert to `0` when cast as `(unsigned char)`.

Comment: @chqrlie String handling <string.h> does have "For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value)." which, I assert , removes the ambiguity.  Rather than `*s1`, better as `*((const unsigned char *)s1)` (in 3 places).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica:  Using `unsigned char const` pointers for the comparison does make a difference in presence of negative zeroes, but does not seem explicitly mandated by the standard, which is a mute point now as two's complement will no longer be supported. My quote is from a C23 draft, and your quote from a previous version is more explicit... I shall update the answer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: the case of ^Z in Windows is a pitiful reminder of MS/DOS' origins as a clone of CP/M whose file system did not store the byte length of files but only the number of sectors.  A ^Z in the last sector was interpreted as an end of file marker for text files, which the library had to test explicitly.  The MS/DOS file system always had a byte length field (initially 24 bits, then 32 bits) hence never needed the ^Z hack.  Support for it could have removed decades ago, as well as the obsolete CR LF end of line sequences, but they continue to plague programmers lifes to this day.

Comment: _continue to plague programmers lives to this day_ --> Old [off-by-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/December_(Roman_month)) problem remains. [Attempted fix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Republican_calendar) did not last.  C'est la vie.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Good point... and this [problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_customary_units) survives [230 years of efforts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrication_in_the_United_States) to still plague engineers' lifes all the way to [Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter)

Comment: @chqrlie USA did decimal currency in 1792, so got that right.  The _later_ metric system was  of lesser importance.  That just my [2¢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_two_cents).

Comment: @chqrlie Concern space exploration: For fun [not using the metric system](https://www.zmescience.com/other/map-of-countries-officially-not-using-the-metric-system/) and [Astronauts on the Moon](https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/b00xq/map_of_countries_that_have_put_men_on_the_moon/)